# One reverse light out on Mondeo MK4, not bulb

Tags: electrical, mondeo

I have a strange problem with my Mondeo MK4 2008. One reverse light (The passenger side on right hand drive car) is not working, while the other is. Reading the manual there are not separate fuses and the bulb is fine.

I put a multimeter on the terminals and read these voltages:
Light off: 50mV
Light on: 2.2 V

So, the 50mV is probably nothing, and the tail light bulb beside it does the same, but the on voltage should be around 12 volts, not a very strange 2.2 V. Again the adjacent tail light bulb reads 11.8, which I'd expect.

Is there any reason why just one reverse light would go out given the bulb has been ruled out?

Is there any reason why the socket would when the light should be on (Vehicle in reverse, ignition on, other light lit) read 2.2 V instead of 12?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is there any corrosion in the socket?

Comment: @Paulster2 Thank you :) And no, I scratched through and around the metal terminal with the probe, it was very clean.

Comment: Have you got a wiring diagram for the vehicle?